# Cycling through a list back and forth

Tags: cycling, iteration, generators

I need an interactive function that works like a generator, whenever it is called it should return "next" or "previous" value from a list. Whenever it reaches the end of the list, it should start over from the beginning (and vice versa when going backwards).

It looks like elisp offers (at least) a couple of ways to iterate forward (generators, cl-loop), but how do I cycle back?

I need something like:

```
(defvar my-list '(:a :b :c))

(defun cycle-through (previous)
  (interactive)
  (if previous
    ;; get previous --
    ;; get next))

(cycle-through)    => :a
(cycle-through)    => :b
(cycle-through t)  => :a
(cycle-through)    => :b
(cycle-through)    => :c
(cycle-through)    => :a
```

What's the best and elegant way of achieving something like that?

*Mind that the list may have duplicate values, trying to store the current value and determine the current position based on that not desirable.*

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways to do it, as you guessed. One simple way is to use a *ring*, which is a list used cyclicly. Standard library `ring.el` defines what you need to create and use rings.

This is from the Commentary at the beginning of `ring.el`:

> This code defines a ring data structure.  A **ring** is a `(hd-index length . vector)`
> list.
>
> You can insert to, remove from, and rotate a ring.  When the ring
> fills up, insertions cause the oldest elts to be quietly dropped.
>
> In `ring-ref`, 0 is the index of the newest element.  Higher indexes
> correspond to older elements.  When the index equals the ring length,
> it wraps to the newest element again.
>
> - `hd-index` = vector index of the oldest ring item.
>
>   Newer items follow this item.  At the end of the vector, they wrap
>   around to the start of the vector.
> - `length` = number of items currently in the ring.
>
>   This never exceeds the length of the vector itself.
>
> These functions are used by the input history mechanism, but they can
> be used for other purposes as well.

You can convert an existing sequence (list, vector, etc.) to a ring using function `ring-convert-sequence-to-ring`.

You can create an empty new ring with function `make-ring`.

You can easily guess what these other functions do:

- `ring-insert`
- `ring-extend`
- `ring-insert+extend`
- `ring-remove`
- `ring-member`
- `ring-elements`
- `ring-next`
- `ring-previous`
- `ring-ref`
- `ring-size`
- `ring-copy`

Comment: Thank you. I just tried it and it is indeed, very nice. I had no idea this existed.